# I'm getting the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oil_paint_regeneration()

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

This is for a WordPress plugin that automatically regenerates and applies oil painting effect to featured images attached to a post published by user_id=1 to user_id=5, 3-5 minutes after the post has been published.

See error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oil_paint_regeneration() in /home/confirment/web/eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/automatic-oil-painting-image-regeneration-algorithm/automatic-oil-painting-image-regeneration-algorithm.php:516 Stack trace: #0 /home/confirment/web/eg.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2314): include_once() #1 /home/confirment/web/eg.com/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php(192): plugin_sandbox_scrape('automatic-oil-p...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/confirment/web/eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/automatic-oil-painting-image-regeneration-algorithm/automatic-oil-painting-image-regeneration-algorithm.php on line 261

Line 259-261:

```
    }
    // run plugin
oil_paint_regeneration();
```

See PHP script below:

```
// Register plugin activation hook
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, "thumbnail_regeneration_activate");
// Register plugin deactivation hook
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, "thumbnail_regeneration_deactivate");
// Plugin activation function
function thumbnail_regeneration_activate() {
        // Schedule event to run 3 minutes after post is published
        wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 180, "thumbnail_regeneration_event");
    }
    // Plugin deactivation function
function thumbnail_regeneration_deactivate() {
        // Remove scheduled event
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook("thumbnail_regeneration_event");
    }
    // Add action for scheduled event
add_action("thumbnail_regeneration_event", "thumbnail_regeneration_event_callback", );
// Event callback function
function thumbnail_regeneration_event_callback() {
        // Get all posts with user_id=1, user_id=2, user_id=3, user_id=4, and user_id=5
        $args = ["author" => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "post_status" => "publish", ];
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        // Loop through each post
        while ($query -> have_posts()) {
            $query -> the_post();
            // Get featured image ID
            $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            // Check if image has already been processed
            if (!get_post_meta($thumbnail_id, "thumbnail_regeneration_processed", true, )) {
                // Get image path
                $image_path = get_attached_file($thumbnail_id);
                // Get image extension
                $image_extension = pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                // Check if image is one of the supported types (jpg, jpeg, png, webm, avif, gif, webp)
                if (in_array($image_type, ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "webm", "avif", "gif", "webp", ])) {
                    // Get the image URL
                    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($image_id);
                    // Use the oil painting filter script to process the image
                    // Create a new image
                    $img = new Image();
                    // Add event listener for when image is loaded
                    $img -> addEventListener("load", function() {
                        // Reduced the size by half for pen and performance.
                        $canvas -> width = $this -> width / 2;
                        $canvas -> height = $this -> height / 2;
                        $ctx -> drawImage($this, 0, 0, $canvas -> width, $canvas -> height, );
                        doOilPaintEffect();
                    });
                }
                // Set image source to the URL
                $img -> src = $image_url;
                // Create GUI for settings
                $gui = new dat().GUI();
                $gui -> add($settings, "intensity");
                $gui -> add($settings, "radius");
                $gui -> add($settings, "ApplyFilter");
                // Function to apply the oil painting effect
                function doOilPaintEffect() {
                        oilPaintEffect($canvas, $settings -> radius, $settings -> intensity, );
                    }
                    // Oil painting filter function
                function oilPaintEffect($canvas, $radius, $intensity) {
                        $width = $canvas -> width;
                        $height = $canvas -> height;
                        $imgData = $ctx -> getImageData(0, 0, $width, $height);
                        $pixData = $imgData -> data;
                        // change to createElement getting added element just for the demo
                        $destCanvas = document.getElementById("dest-canvas");
                        $dCtx = $destCanvas -> getContext("2d");
                        $pixelIntensityCount = [];
                        $destCanvas -> width = $width;
                        $destCanvas -> height = $height;
                        $destImageData = $dCtx -> createImageData($width, $height);
                        $destPixData = $destImageData -> data;
                        $intensityLUT = [];
                        $rgbLUT = [];
                        for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
                            $intensityLUT[$y] = [];
                            $rgbLUT[$y] = [];
                            for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
                                $idx = ($y * $width + $x) * 4;
                                $r = $pixData[$idx];
                                $g = $pixData[$idx + 1];
                                $b = $pixData[$idx + 2];
                                $avg = ($r + $g + $b) / 3;
                                $intensityLUT[$y][$x] = round(
                                    ($avg * $intensity) / 255, );
                                $rgbLUT[$y][$x] = ["r" => $r, "g" => $g, "b" => $b, ];
                            }
                        }
                        for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
                            for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
                                $pixelIntensityCount = [];
                                // Find intensities of nearest pixels within radius.
                                for ($yy = -$radius; $yy <= $radius; $yy++) {
                                    for ($xx = -$radius; $xx <= $radius; $xx++) {
                                        if ($y + $yy > 0 && $y + $yy < $height && $x + $xx > 0 && $x + $xx < $width) {
                                            $intensityVal = $intensityLUT[$y + $yy][$x + $xx];
                                            if (!isset($pixelIntensityCount[$intensityVal], )) {
                                                $pixelIntensityCount[$intensityVal] = ["val" => 1, "r" => $rgbLUT[$y + $yy][$x + $xx]["r"], "g" => $rgbLUT[$y + $yy][$x + $xx]["g"], "b" => $rgbLUT[$y + $yy][$x + $xx]["b"], ];
                                            } else {
                                                $pixelIntensityCount[$intensityVal]["val"] ++;
                                                $pixelIntensityCount[$intensityVal]["r"] += $rgbLUT[$y + $yy][$x + $xx]["r"];
                                                $pixelIntensityCount[$intensityVal]["g"] += $rgbLUT[$y + $yy][$x + $xx]["g"];
                                                $pixelIntensityCount[$intensityVal]["b"] += $rgbLUT[$y + $yy][$x + $xx]["b"];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                usort($pixelIntensityCount, function($a, $b) {
                                    return $b["val"] - $a["val"];
                                });
                                $curMax = $pixelIntensityCount[0]["val"];
                                $dIdx = ($y * $width + $x) * 4;
                                $destPixData[$dIdx] = ~~($pixelIntensityCount[0]["r"] / $curMax);
                                $destPixData[$dIdx + 1] = ~~($pixelIntensityCount[0]["g"] / $curMax);
                                $destPixData[$dIdx + 2] = ~~($pixelIntensityCount[0]["b"] / $curMax);
                                $destPixData[$dIdx + 3] = 255;
                            }
                        }
                        $dCtx -> putImageData($destImageData, 0, 0);
                        // check if image has been processed before
                        $imageName = pathinfo($imgUrl, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        if (strpos($imageName, "_oil_painted") !== false) {
                            // image has been processed before, do not process again
                            return;
                        }
                        // save image to server
                        $newImageName = $imageName.
                        "_oil_painted.".
                        pathinfo($imgUrl, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        imagejpeg($canvas, $newImageName);
                        // update featured image
                        update_post_meta($postId, "_thumbnail_id", $newImageName);
                    }
                    // hook function to run after post is published
                add_action("publish_post", "auto_oil_paint_featured_image");

                function auto_oil_paint_featured_image($postId) {
                        // check if user is one of the specified users
                        $userIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
                        if (!in_array(get_post_field("post_author", $postId), $userIds)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        // schedule event to run 3-5 minutes after post is published
                        $time = time() + (3 + rand(0, 2)) * 60;
                        wp_schedule_single_event($time, "oil_paint_featured_image", [
                            $postId,
                        ]);
                    }
                    // hook function to run scheduled event
                add_action("oil_paint_featured_image", "oil_paint_featured_image_func", );
                // function to run scheduled event
                function oil_paint_featured_image_func() {
                    // get all newly published post by user_id=1, user_id=2, user_id=3, user_id=4, and user_id=5
                    $args = ["author" => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "post_status" => "publish", "numberposts" => -1, ];
                    $posts = get_posts($args);
                    // loop through each post
                    foreach($posts as $post) {
                            // get the featured image of the post
                            $featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post -> ID);
                            $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($featured_image_id, );
                            // check if image is one of the supported types (jpg, jpeg, png, webm, avif, gif, webp)
                            if (in_array(pathinfo($featured_image_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "webm", "avif", "gif", "webp", ], )) {
                                // check if image has already been processed by the plugin
                                if (!get_post_meta($featured_image_id, "oil_paint_processed", true, )) {
                                    // get the path to the image
                                    $image_path = get_attached_file($featured_image_id);
                                    // check if image is one of the supported types (jpg, jpeg, png, webm, avif, gif, webp)
                                    if (in_array(pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "webm", "avif", "gif", "webp", ], )) {
                                        // get the image data
                                        $img = wp_get_image_editor($image_path);
                                        // apply oil paint filter
                                        $img -> oil_paint($radius, $intensity);
                                        // save the processed image
                                        $img -> save($image_path);
                                        // update the post meta to indicate that this image has been processed
                                        update_post_meta($featured_image_id, "oil_paint_processed", true, );
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // hook function to run scheduled event
                    add_action("oil_paint_featured_image", "oil_paint_featured_image", );
                    // function to register the plugin
                    function oil_paint_thumbnail_regeneration_plugin() {
                        // get all users
                        $users = get_users(["fields" => ["ID"]]);
                        // loop through each user
                        foreach($users as $user) {
                            // get all posts by the current user
                            $args = ["author" => $user -> ID, "post_status" => "publish", ];
                            $posts = get_posts($args);
                            // loop through each post
                            foreach($posts as $post) {
                                    // get the featured image
                                    $featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post -> ID, );
                                    // check if image has already been processed by the plugin
                                    if (!get_post_meta($featured_image_id, "oil_paint_processed", true, )) {
                                        // get image path
                                        $image_path = get_attached_file($featured_image_id, );
                                        // check if image is one of the supported types (jpg, jpeg, png, webm, avif, gif, webp)
                                        if (in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION, ), ), ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "webm", "avif", "gif", "webp", ], )) {
                                            // create new image with oil paint filter applied
                                            $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_path), );
                                            $filter_image = imageoilpaint($image, $settings["radius"], $settings["intensity"], );
                                            // save the new image with a unique name
                                            $new_image_path = str_replace(".jpg", "_oil_paint.jpg", $image_path, );
                                            imagejpeg($filter_image, $new_image_path);
                                            // update the featured image for the post
                                            update_post_meta($post_id, "_thumbnail_id", $new_image_path, );
                                            // update the post meta to indicate the image has been processed by the plugin
                                            update_post_meta($post_id, "oil_paint_processed", true, );
                                            // cleanup
                                            imagedestroy($image);
                                            imagedestroy($filter_image);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // schedule the event to run 3-5 minutes after a post is published
                            add_action("publish_post", "schedule_oil_paint_featured_image", );

                            function schedule_oil_paint_featured_image($post_id) {
                                    wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 180, "oil_paint_featured_image", [$post_id], );
                                }
                                // activate the plugin
                            register_activation_hook(FILE, "schedule_oil_paint_featured_image", );
                            // deactivate the plugin
                            register_deactivation_hook(FILE, "deactivate_oil_paint_regeneration", );

                            function deactivate_oil_paint_regeneration() {
                                    // remove scheduled event
                                    wp_clear_scheduled_hook("oil_paint_featured_image");
                                }
                                // activate the plugin
                            register_activation_hook(FILE, "activate_oil_paint_regeneration", );

                            function activate_oil_paint_regeneration() {
                                // schedule event to run every 3-5 minutes
                                if (!wp_next_scheduled("oil_paint_featured_image")) {
                                    wp_schedule_event(time(), "every_3_5_minutes", "oil_paint_featured_image", );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // run plugin
oil_paint_regeneration();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contact the plugin support forum for help with plugins; it's not within the scope of support here.

But the error means that the function `oil_paint_regeneration` isn't available at that time in the processing of the site. Could be that the plugin is not loading their functions at the proper time.

But, the plugin guys need to fix this.